# Conditional For-Each in XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Need your help to validate if below XSLT code is correct.

My input XML would look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
        <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>New York</name>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>Boston</name>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>Boston</name>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>Boston</name>
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment>
            <type>B</type>
            <name>Chicago</name>
        </Assignment>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

My output file should look like below after transformation

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Update_Data>
    <Records>
        <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
        <Record_Location>
            <Location>
                <order>1</order>
                <name>New York</name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <order>2</order>
                <name>Boston</name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <order>3</order>
                <name>Boston</name>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <order>4</order>
                <name>Boston</name>
            </Location>
        </Record_Location>
        <Record_Location>
            <Location>
                <order>1</order>
                <name>Chicago</name>
            </Location>
        </Record_Location>
    </Records>
</Update_Data>
```

I have written following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Update_Data>
            <Records>
                <Batch_number><xsl:value-of select="Workers/Worker/Batch_number"/></Batch_number>
                    <Record_Location>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Workers/Worker/Assignment[type='A']">

                            <Location>
                                <order>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                </order>
                                <name>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                </name>
                            </Location>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </Record_Location>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Workers/Worker/Assignment[type='B']">
                        <Record_Location>
                        <Location>
                                <order>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                </order>
                                <name>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                </name>
                            </Location>
                            </Record_Location>
                            </xsl:for-each>
            </Records>
        </Update_Data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Requirements for transformation.

If value of  is same and it's appearing multiple times in input XML, Location elements(under Record_Location tag) need to be created as many times as  is exists in the file with respective values.

for .e.g. `<type>` is A appearing 4 times in input xml, so four `<Location>` elements need to be created  tag should hold sequenced value.

`<type>` is B appearing only once, so only one  element needs to be present in the output file.

Number of `<Record_Location>` elements in the output should be same as unique values of `<type>`. In my example, only two unique values are present i.e. A and B, so my output should have only two `<Record_Location>`

XSLT code that i have written yields expected result. But, I'm not sure if this is the efficient way to write the code for my requirement. Is there a way to consolidate the for-each conditions by not specifying type='A' or type='B' etc.. Input XML can contain multiple different types. Or is it even possible to write a code without a `for-each` loop

Can someone please take a look at this and suggest best approach please?

-thanks 
Anoop

---

After incorporating Martin's suggestion in XSLT.. I got something like below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Update_Data>
            <Records>
                <Batch_number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Workers/Worker/Batch_number"/>
                </Batch_number>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Workers/Worker/Assignment" group-by="type">
                    <Record_Location>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </Record_Location>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Records>
        </Update_Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Assignment">
        <Location>
            <order>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </order>
            <name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
            </name>
        </Location>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Use grouping e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="Assignment" group-by="type"><Record_Location><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></Record_Location></xsl:for-each-group>` and then set up a template matching `Assignment` to map to `Location`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your help. I just updated my original question with the improvised code based on your suggestion. Can you suggest if there is an alternate way to sequence the number other than using position()

Comment: I think using `position()` here seems the right and appropriate tool given your input, the grouping you now have and that you push the `current-group()` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` to a template. Unless you can explain why you don't want to use position() respectively what determines that number in the `order` element I am not sure there is a need to rewrite that approach.

Comment: Alright, thanks again Martin. My question around position() was generic. Was curious to know other way to get the sequenced number in the output.